# Чи є літературним слово заколка?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

Чи є літературним слово **заколка** (похідне від ***заколювати волосся***)? У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakolka) цього слова немає. Дуже часто чую це слово від багатьох людей та навіть на сайті [Копійочка](https://kopiyochka.com.ua/zakolka_dlya_volossya_kvti/) його побачила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справді, слова заколка немає у Сумі. Однак, є словникова стаття із дієсловом [заколоти](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakoloty), яка містить значення 2 з відсиланням:

> **ЗАКОЛОТИ** 2 див. *заколювати*.

Шукаємо далі:

> **ЗАКОЛЮВАТИ**, юю, юєш, недок., *ЗАКОЛОТИ,* олю, олеш, док., перех. Пришпилювати чим-небудь одяг, волосся і т. ін. Хима завилась гарною наміткою, заколола її здоровими шпильками з червоними головками (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 87).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakoljuvaty).

[Російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%97%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9A%D0%90&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) подають:

> *Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009*–
>   **Заколка**, разг. – **шпилька.**
>     *Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)*
>
> **При́шпилька – булавка, заколка.**

Отже, нормативно вживати **шпилька** на позначення предмету, що заколює волосся. Уникання **заколка** в українській мові (оскільки є заколювати - то теоретично може існувати), можливо, подібне до вживання віддієслівних іменники з суфіксом -**к-**, для яких основним є предметне значення (продукту, наслідку дії, об’єкта, предмета, за допомогою якого здійснюють дію, зрідка місця дії (виписка, в’язка, грілка, закладка, збірка, пересадка, підтяжка, посилка, присипка). [Браковка чи бракування? Колібаба Л.М.](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/Structure/Departments/Department3/Pages/recommends.aspx)